# How to enable Logger.debug() in Log4j

Tags: java, log4j

While trying to execute the following lines only the last two statements are displayed("Here is some ERROR" and "Here is some FATAL") and the first three statements are not displayed.I had just started to learn this topic, can anyone tell why is this happening?

```
    logger.debug("Here is some DEBUG");
    logger.info("Here is some INFO");
    logger.warn("Here is some WARN");
    logger.error("Here is some ERROR");
    logger.fatal("Here is some FATAL");
```

the log4j.property has

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug,stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] %d{mm:ss}(%F:%M:%L)%n%m%n%n
```

Comment: But I have log4j.properties is that not enough?

Comment: Can you post your log4j.properties file?

Comment: you should not name it `log4j.property`, it should be `log4j.properties`

Comment: sorry while editing i made the mistake, it is log4j.properties only

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but have you told your Logger where the property file is? This you do by calling PropertyConfigurator.configure(pathToPropFile);

Comment: Where should I make this call? I've a GWT app, but i don´t know where I can call PropertyConfigurator...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You probably have a log4j.properties file somewhere in the project. In that file you can configure which level of debug output you want. See this example:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.example=debug
```

The first line sets the log level for the root logger to "info", i.e. only info, warn, error and fatal will be printed to the console (which is the appender defined a little below that).

The last line sets the logger for com.example.* (if you get your loggers via `LogFactory.getLogger(getClass())`) will be at debug level, i.e. debug will also be printed.

Comment: It might also be a log4j.xml file, which is a XML file that is used instead of a Java Properties file.

Answer (score 57):

Here's a quick one-line hack that I occasionally use to temporarily turn on log4j debug logging in a JUnit test:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

or if you want to avoid adding imports:

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(
      org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG);
```

The equivalent for log4j2 is:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getRootLogger(); 
Configurator.setAllLevels(logger.getName(), Level.getLevel(level))
```

Thanks to [Jeryl Cook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/436183/jeryl-cook)

Comment: for log4j2  do this Logger logger = LogManager.getRootLogger();
Configurator.setAllLevels(logger.getName(), Level.getLevel(level));

Answer (score 11):

Put a file named `log4j.xml` into your classpath. Contents are e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: He already has a Properties file. I believe in the latest version of log4j, it's recommended that you use XML instead, but it's not required that you do so - a Properties file can be used.

Comment: so what should i do to rectify the problem?

Answer (score 6):

This is probably happening because your log4j configuration is set to `ERROR`. Look for a log4j.properties file with contents like the following:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, CONSOLE

# console logging
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %-20.20t %-24c{1}: %m%n
```

The `rootLogger` is set to `ERROR` level here using a `CONSOLE` appender.

Note that some appenders like the console appender also have a `Threshold` property that can be used to overrule the `rootLoggers` level. You need to check both in this case.

Answer (score 6):

If you are coming here because you are using Apache commons logging with log4j and log4j isn't working as you expect then check that you actually have a log4j.jar in your run-time classpath. That one had me puzzled for a little while. I have now configured the runner in my dev environment to include **-Dlog4j.debug** in the Java command line so I can always see that Log4j is being initialized correctly

Comment: or make sure you're not using slf4j-simple jar and replace with slf4j-log4j12

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the logger level to the lowest you want to display. For example, if you want to display DEBUG messages, you need to set the logger level to DEBUG.

The [Apache log4j manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) has a section on Configuration.

Comment: i didnt know what was the problem in the last program, but i copied the same code and executed in a different path and its working now

Answer (score 3):

I like to use a rolling file appender to write the logging info to a file. My log4j properties file typically looks something like this. I prefer this way since I like to make package specific logging in case I need varying degrees of logging for different packages. Only one package is mentioned in the example.

```
log4j.appender.RCS=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RCS.File.DateFormat='.'yyyy-ww
#define output location
log4j.appender.RCS.File=C:temp/logs/MyService.log
#define the file layout
log4j.appender.RCS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RCS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a} %5 %c{1}: Line#%L - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=warn
#Define package specific logging
log4j.logger.MyService=debug, RCS
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening due to the fact that the logging level of your logger is set to 'error' - therefore you will only see error messages or above this level in terms of severity so this is why you also see the 'fatal' message.

If you set the logging level to 'debug' on your logger in your log4j.xml you should see all messages.

Have a look at the [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) introduction for explaination.