# how to change to debug mode in java

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm trying to use logger in java jvm.  but I can't change the logger mode.
I can see only "info" message and I want to see also "debug" message.

I tried to change to debug mode in `log4j.xml` in this way:

```
``<appender name="DISCOVERY" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/tmp/ncs-logs/jvm-discovery-app.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10000KB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="100"/>       
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">  
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c{2}]:%L %m%n"/>               
        </layout>                                                                 
    </appender>                                                                 

   <!-- value="&#60;%-4p&#62; %d{dd-MMM-yyyy::HH:mm:ss.SSS} %C{1} %t: - %m%n" -->

   <logger name="com.lte.btscompact.mngmt.sync.app">                                                
        <level value="DEBUG" />                                                    
        <appender-ref ref="DISCOVERY"/>                                                  
   </logger>                                                                   

   <root>
       <appender-ref ref="DISCOVERY" /> 
    </root>

    </log4j:configuration>
```

and in cli I did this command:
set java-vm java-logging logger com.tailf.packages.ned.acs level level-all

but I still can't see debug message.
what else should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to display debug level log messages for java.util.logging or log4j

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable Logger.debug() in Log4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673485/how-to-enable-logger-debug-in-log4j)

Comment: share complete log4j.xml file. What is Root Log Level defined?

Comment: I update in the code below the whole log4j.xml
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your appender config - it must not have a threshold higher than DEBUG:

```
<param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
```

versus

```
<param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
```