# Log event calls in tapestry

Tags: java, events, logging, tapestry

I want to log all event calls. For example if a user clicks on an `ActionLink` I want to get the information that the event `Action` just occurred.

In the [documentation](https://tapestry.apache.org/logging.html) regarding logging it is stated that it's possible, but I don't quite understand how to do it. It says:

> Tapestry can also debug component event logic. The component's logger, with a "tapestry.events." prefix, is used at debug level. The debugging output identifies the event name and event source, and identifies any methods that are invoked.
>
> Note that events that are not handled by a component will bubble up to
>   the component's container; further logging for the same event will
>   occur using the logger associated with the container. The page
>   containing the initial component is the final step when logging.

It's not really an instruction. I tried something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1673684/7700150), but I couldn't find a way to enable an event logging property of the logger. Currently I only set my logger to debug level like this:

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG);   
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("de.[...].Edit").setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

But this only seems to enable debugging level and events are still untracked.

Also note that out of some reason I currently can't find my `log4j.properties` (log4j doesn't complain about it tho, so it probably does exist somewhere) file, so a solution without the requirement of this file would be nice. If that's not possible, it wouldn't be a problem either, I'd simply create a new properties file then or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I only had to properly read the documentation. The event logger is received like this:

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger eventLogger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("tapestry.events.de.[...].Edit");
```

Which can then be set to debug similar to the normal logger:

```
eventLogger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```